# Как в Joomla проверить что пользователь состоит только в указанной группе?

Tags: php, joomla

Хочу для Всех пользователей, которые в группе "регистр", показать сообщение, а для тех, кто в других группах, не показывать.
Как сделать такую проверку в Joomla 3?
Начало есть а как дальше id шруппы регистр 2

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$user->groups
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->get('groups');

foreach($groups as $group) {
   $userGroup = $group; // ID группы пользователя
}

if($userGroup == 2){
   echo 'привет';
}
```

или можно просто проверить пользователя на "не гостя", но тогда войдут не только, зарегистрированные, а супер юзер, менеджер и т.д.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();  
if (!$user->guest) {
    echo 'авторизован';
}
```

Comment: Это получается так
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$user->get('2');
if($user == 2) { echo "Привет"; }

Comment: Сорри, тот код не работает в Joomla 3, он устарел, исправил ответ